# DBInputWritable throwing Exception

Tags: hadoop

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBWritable;


public class DBInputWritable implements Writable, DBWritable
{
        String symbol;
        String date;
        double open;
        double high;
        double low;
        double close;
        int volume;
        double adjClose;

          //private final static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

          public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException
          {
           symbol=in.readLine();
           date=in.readLine();
           open=in.readDouble();
           high=in.readDouble();
           low=in.readDouble();
           close=in.readDouble();
           volume=in.readInt();
           adjClose=in.readDouble();

          }

          public void readFields(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
          {
           symbol = rs.getString(2);
           date = rs.getString(3);
           open = rs.getDouble(4);
           high = rs.getDouble(5);
           low = rs.getDouble(6);
           close = rs.getDouble(7);
           volume = rs.getInt(8);
           adjClose = rs.getDouble(9);
          }

          public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
          {

          }

          public void write( PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException
          {

          }

          public String getSymbol()
          {
            return symbol;
          }


          public  String getDate()
          {
            return date;
          }

          public double getOpen()
          {
            return open;
          }

          public double getHigh()
          {
            return high;
          }

          public double getLow()
          {
            return low;
          }

          public double getClose()
          {
            return close;
          }

          public int getVolume()
          {
            return volume;
          }

          public double getAdjClose()
           {
            return adjClose;
           }

}


public class DBOutputWritable implements Writable, DBWritable
{

         String symbol;
         String date;
         double open;
         double high;
         double low;
         double close;
         int volume;
         double adjClose;
         ;




       public DBOutputWritable(String symbol,String date,String open,String high,String low,String close,String volume,String adjClose)

       {

           this.symbol=symbol;
           this.date=date;
           this.open=Double.parseDouble(open);
           this.high=Double.parseDouble(high);
           this.low=Double.parseDouble(low);
           this.close=Double.parseDouble(close);
           this.volume=Integer.parseInt(volume);
           this.adjClose=Double.parseDouble(adjClose);

       }
       public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException
       {

       }


       public void readFields(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
       {

       }


       public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
       {
         out.writeChars(symbol);
         out.writeChars(date);
         out.writeDouble(open);
         out.writeDouble(high);
         out.writeDouble(low);
         out.writeDouble(close);
         out.writeInt(volume);
         out.writeDouble(adjClose);

       }


       public void write(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException
       {

          ps.setString(1,symbol);
          ps.setString(2,date);
          ps.setDouble(3,open);
          ps.setDouble(4,high);
          ps.setDouble(5,low);
          ps.setDouble(6,close);
          ps.setInt(7,volume);
          ps.setDouble(8,adjClose);
         }



   }   

    public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable,DBInputWritable,Text,Text>
    {

    public void  map(LongWritable key,  DBInputWritable value, Context ctx)
    {
              try
                    {   
                  Text set;
                  set= new Text(value.getDate());
                  String line = value.getSymbol()+","+value.getDate()+","+value.getOpen()+","+value.getHigh()+","+value.getLow()+","+value.getClose()+","+value.getVolume()+","+value.getAdjClose();

                       ctx.write(set,new Text(line));

                     }

         catch(IOException e)
          {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }

         catch(InterruptedException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
    }

public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, DBOutputWritable, NullWritable>
{



   public void reduce(Text key, Text value, Context ctx)
   {

        try
             {
               String []line= value.toString().split(",");

                    String sym=line[0];
                    String dt=line[1];
                    String opn=line[2];
                    String hgh=line[3];
                    String lw=line[4];
                    String cls=line[5];
                    String vlm=line[6];
                    String adcls=line[7];               


          ctx.write(new DBOutputWritable(sym,dt,opn,hgh,lw,cls,vlm,adcls),NullWritable.get());

                }

         catch(IOException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

          catch(InterruptedException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
   }



  public class Main
    {

         public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception

    {

     Configuration conf = new Configuration();

     DBConfiguration.configureDB(conf,
    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",             //Driver Class
    "jdbc:mysql://192.168.198.128:3306/testDb",   //DB URL
    "sqoopuser",      //USERNAME
    "passphrase");  //PASSWORD

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(DBOutputWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(DBInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(DBOutputFormat.class);

    DBInputFormat.setInput(
    job,
    DBInputWritable.class,
    "aapldata",    //input table name
    null,
    null,
    new String[] {"stock","symbol", "date" ,"open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adjClose"}
    //Table Columns
    );

    DBOutputFormat.setOutput(
    job,
    "aapldatanew", //Output Table Name
    new String[] {"symbol", "date" ,"open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adjClose"}
    //Table Columns
    );

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }

    }
```

**I think Code is picture perfect. But still I encounter below error:**

```
14/11/26 22:09:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/11/26 22:09:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
14/11/26 22:09:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201411262208_0001_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lidb.DBWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat$DBRecordWriter.write(DBOutputFormat.java:66
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Need your valuable Insights.

Comment: It will be more readable, if you spent some time to align the code

Answer (score 0):

In your `map` class get the input as text instead of `DBInputWritable`:

```
public class Map extends Mapper {
  public void map(LongWritable key,Text value, Context ctx)
```

Comment: Nope.. Mapper is running just Fine.. Problem is at reducer. I am able to read values from DB but for some reason it is unable to write.Refer to the error once.

Answer (score 0):

I can find 2 problems:

1. mapper output key,value classes not matching with the job configuration. Please chek it.
   mapper  while jobconfigured. *Please correct as your need. I approach     the 2nd problem considering mapper key,value pair is your right choice.*
2. you **didn't override** `reduce` method !!

As per your `job` configurationThe signature should be:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context){
         //...your code
}
```

**Explanation for your exception**

Since you didn't override Reducer's reduce, the reducer will reduce with the default implementation(which is called identity reducer).Source code:

```
protected void reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, Context context
                      ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   for(VALUEIN value: values) {
   context.write((KEYOUT) key, (VALUEOUT) value);
 }
}
```

As specified in the source code it simply iterate over values and write it using Output key value calsses.But in your case intermmediate  pairs(i.e IntWritable,Text) do not match with  pairs of DBoutputFormat.

HTH !

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your insights. I see that I wrongly posted a different Main class. I apologize for my mistake. Please check the error now. meanwhile i'll try modifying the reducer as you suggested. But i dont think. Iterable is mandatory. As you can see the keys of mapper output are unique already. there is no scope for aggregation at reducer's side. So we dont need an iterator for single value i suppose.

Comment: No, you need to override reduce method as specified.Otherwise it will go on with default implementation as explained.Since it is very well cleared from exception it's taken default impl !